# Android Espresso: EditText with input type number

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-espresso

I want to test my android app with Espresso. I have an `editText` with `android:inputType="number"`.

If I write smth like that on my test:

```
onView(withId(R.id.editTextNumber)).perform(typeText("15"));
```

It doesn't work. But since typeText doesn't take an integer, how can I perform this test ?

Thanks :)

Comment: @Shark My test doesn't work. My editText only accept numbers as inputs, but the typeText method only take a String as arg.

Comment: What is failing, how is it failing? Could you post the logcat or the error that this approach results in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
onView(withId(blabla)).peform(typeText(String.valueOf("15"));
```

https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/advanced/index.html

if you can't find any way to enter numbers into your EditText, you'll have to avoid using `typeText` and do it by injecting KeyEvents, and press numbers.

Comment: It works with the String.valueof(). But it's my Android Studio who had a problem, because typeText("15") works on a computer friend... Thanks :)